# How do I resolve a "connection refused" error with Perl module for Stanford Natural Language Processor

Tags: perl, stanford-nlp

I'm kicking the tires of some NLP modules in Perl. I have installed [Text::NLP::Stanford::EntityExtract](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::NLP::Stanford::EntityExtract) (I had to force install because of an `refused connection` error, cited below).

I have also downloaded and installed the required Java files and ran the following command:

`java -server -mx400m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz 1234`

The response back was:

`Loading classifier from classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.1 sec].`

so it seemed to work.

However, when I run the code straight from the POD for the module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use Text::NLP::Stanford::EntityExtract;
my $ner = Text::NLP::Stanford::EntityExtract->new;
my $server = $ner->server;
my @txt = ("Some text\n\n", "Treated as \\n\\n delimited paragraphs");
my @tagged_text = $ner->get_entities(@txt);
my $entities = $ner->entities_list($txt[0]); # rather complicated
                                             # @AOA based data
                                             # structure for further
                                             # processing
```

I get the following error:

`Connection refused at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.4/Text/NLP/Stanford/EntityExtract.pm line 84.`

Not sure what I can try to resolve this. When I run `lsof -n -i:1234 | grep LISTEN` I get no response back so it looks like the server is not running.

Answer (score 2):

I did a port scan and it turns out the service is running on my machine on port 4465, not port 1234. Either the README.txt file is out of date or the `1234` at the end of the command in the README.txt file is not a port like I thought.

Comment: Examples at https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml do not show a port number at end of command line and `java -server` does not seem to specifically mandate a port, this is completely up the application. The Java source file has `Defaut port is 4465` and `Usage: {@code java edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer [-loadClassifier fileOrResource|-client] -port portNumber}` note the `-port` :-) I guess the documentation is wrong...